# Given probability density function $f(x)=2x $ on $[0,1]$, find the expectation

Tags: probability, expectation

> Probability density function is $ y = 2x $ for $[0,1]$, it is zero anywhere else.
>
> What is the expectation?

I think it is $E[X]=\int_0^1 x2x dx=\frac{2}{3}x^3|_0^1=\frac{2}{3}$

This is not correct, it should be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: the mess of the left is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\times 2\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}/2 = \frac{1}{2}$.  The total mess is 1.

Comment: Your solution is quite alright. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ is obviously not the correct one.

Comment: Sorry,  I am so stupid.

Comment: @lulu Why? You got it right. Also, I love that you write "mess" for "mass". Intended or not, I think it’s terrific.

Comment: @DanZimm The integral of $2x$ from $x=0$ to $x=1$ is... well, $1$.

Comment: @Did oh wow I wasn't integrating, silly me!

Answer (score 1):

$E[X] = \dfrac23 \approx 0.667$ as you have correctly calculated.

$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\approx 0.707$ is in fact the [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) rather than the mean, in the sense that both $$\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} 2x \; dx = \frac12$$ and $$\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^1 2x \; dx = \frac12.$$